# How to get unique results in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am using this JPA-Query (EclipseLink):

```
SELECT e FROM Entity e GROUP BY e.label
```

But i get all rows in my result instead of only the unique labels.

My second approach was using DISTINCT like i did successfully in another function which counts the distinct values, but i don't know how apply this to get the Entities:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.label) FROM Entity e
```

Comment: grou by is an aggregate function. If you have multiple entity objects with the same label, which one do you want returned?

Comment: I'm surprised to first query is even valid. What would you like to select?

Comment: I want to select any of the Entities with the same label

Comment: @Martin: you mean `select e from Entity e where e.label = 'blah'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Hibernate JP-QL documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-aggregation):

```
select distinct e.label from Entity e
```

However, it seems you want the full entities, which I don't think is possible.

Comment: I ended up with using a query like this. And then i run another query to get all Entities with a specific label.

Answer (score 1):

actually, it is possible, for example :

```
    @NamedQuery(name = "WorkingDay.WorkersAtADay", query = "SELECT DISTINCT w.worker FROM WorkingDay w WHERE w.date = :Date"),
```